# How can I move files and folders up one level within the distribution directory?

Tags: github-actions

I am working on making a GitHub Actions pipeline for the deployment of an Angular app.

I have the following YAML file:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - MyApp

  on:
    push:
      branches:
        - develop
    workflow_dispatch:

  jobs:
    build:
      runs-on: windows-latest

      steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Set up Node.js version
          uses: actions/setup-node@v3
          with:
            node-version: '18.x'

        - name: npm install, build, and test
          run: |
            npm install
            npm run build --if-present
            npm run test --if-present
            working-directory: MyApp/Client
        
        - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
          uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
          with:
            name: node-app
            path: .

    deploy:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: build
      environment:
        name: 'Production'
        url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
      permissions:
        id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

      steps:
        - name: Download artifact from build job
          uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
          with:
            name: node-app
        
        - name: Login to Azure
          uses: azure/login@v1
          with:
            client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_8BE42F6E30C94F48858C31874D456T66 }}
            tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_4D319904D267451A923F927A13E18BB5 }}
            subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_2DD3B93AD1664822A483B09CD6697224 }}

        - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
          uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
          id: deploy-to-webapp
          with:
            app-name: 'MyApp'
            slot-name: 'Production'
            package: .
```

The file-structure resulting from executing `ng build --configuration=production` is represented below

```
dist
├── maindirectory
│   ├── file1.js
│   ├── file2.js
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── image1.png
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── index.html
│── secondarydirectory
│   ├── file3.js
│   ├── file4.js
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── image2.png
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── index.html
```

When doing a *manual* deploy, after executing the build command, I drag all the contents of `maindirectory` out into the `dist`, then I delete the (now empty) `maindirectory`. The tree now bwcomes:

```
dist
├── file1.js
├── file2.js
├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── image1.png
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── index.html
│── secondarydirectory
│   ├── file3.js
│   ├── file4.js
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── image2.png
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── common.js
│   ├── index.html
```

I want to achieve the same tree structure from the automated deploy, via the pipeline.

What changes must I do to the YAML file in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Make your `build` script do the right thing _wherever_ it's run, e.g. through configuration or even a `postbuild` script. Also it makes no sense to have `--if-present` in the pipeline.

Comment: This continues to have really nothing to do with where it's run or that it's a YAML file. Moving directories around is a basic task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline script involves manually rearranging files after the build process, which is not very reliable method in a CI/CD context: it adds inconsistency and potential errors, since it relies on an external process outside the automated pipeline.

It is better automating the file restructuring within the build process itself: you would get consistency and repeatability, important for any automated deployment process.

Adding a post-build script in your project's `package.json` to handle the file movement:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "postbuild": "mv dist/maindirectory/* dist/ && rm -rf dist/maindirectory",
    "test": "..."
}
```

The `--if-present` flag would suppress errors, potentially allowing the pipeline to pass despite critical issues. If the `build` or `test` scripts are accidentally removed or misnamed, the pipeline would not execute these steps, but it would still succeed.
So, remove, as commented, the `--if-present` flags. The build step would be:

```yaml
- name: npm install, build, and test
    run: |
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm test
    working-directory: MyApp/Client
```

The `npm run build` command now automatically triggers the `postbuild` script after the build process completes, making sure the file structure is always as desired.

Your workflow would be:

```bash
GitHub Repo
   |__ (Push to develop branch)
   |__ GitHub Actions Pipeline (Updated YAML)
        |__ Build Job (Windows)
        |    |__ Checkout
        |    |__ Setup Node.js
        |    |__ npm install, build (with postbuild), test
        |    |__ Upload artifact
        |
        |__ Deploy Job (Ubuntu)
             |__ Download artifact
             |__ Login to Azure
             |__ Deploy to Azure Web App
```

It includes the file movement logic within the project, making it independent of the CI/CD pipeline.

---

> I run `npm run build` and I get `'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command` from the VS Code terminal.

The error message "mv is not recognized as an internal or external command" means you are using a Windows environment, where the `mv` command (a Unix/Linux command for moving files) is not natively available. Windows uses different commands for file operations.

You could modify the `postbuild` script in the `package.json` to use Windows command line syntax, or, better yet, use a cross-platform solution.
A cross-platform approach would involve using Node.js scripts or a [package like `shx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) which provides Unix-like commands for `npm` scripts and works across different operating systems.

`npm install shx --save-dev` (That will add `shx` to your `package.json` under `devDependencies`) and update the `postbuild` script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "postbuild": "shx mv dist/maindirectory/* dist/ && shx rm -rf dist/maindirectory && shx rm -rf dist/secondarydirectory/web.config",
    "test": "..."
}
```

Commit and push the updated `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to your repository.

Your GitHub Actions workflow does not need to be significantly altered. The critical step is make sure that dependencies are installed:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm run build
          npm run test
        working-directory: MyApp/Client

      # rest of the workflow
```

In this workflow, `npm install` will automatically install `shx` since it is part of your `devDependencies`, making it available for use in your npm scripts.

Comment: I added `"postbuild": "mv dist/maindirectory/* dist/ && rm -rf dist/maindirectory && rm -rf dist/secondarydirectory/web.config"` to package.json, I run `ng build --configuration=production`  and nothing happend but the build. So no file moving.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir `ng build`? It should be `npm run build`, no? The `package.json` script build section will call `ng build`. And add an echo for debug: `"postbuild": "echo Running postbuild && mv dist/maindirectory/* dist/ && rm -rf dist/maindirectory && rm -rf dist/secondarydirectory/web.config"`

Comment: I run `npm run build` and I get `'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command` from the VS Code terminal.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I hav edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Please five an answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77939284/4512005)** too. Thanks!