# What causes this Google Chrome related GitHub Actions problem?

Tags: azure, github-actions

I a working on a .NET 7 and Angular 16 app.

I have set a continuous deployment pipeline for the frontend in Azure, using a wizard (provided by Azure):

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - MyApp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        working-directory: MyApp/Client
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
          npm run test
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_6UI42F6E30C94F48858C318747E2A3E3 }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_3F119904D267451A923F927A13E15678 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_1SS2B93AD1664822A483B09CD6697234 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'MyApp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
```

When the Github Actions run, the step `npm install, build, and test` fails with the error:

```
Chrome 121.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
```

What causes the error? What is the most reliable way to fix it?

Comment: what type of testing are you doing ? ui testing requiring a browser ?

Comment: @Thomas No, the browser is not required.

Comment: can you try to isolated the issue ? having separated tasks for  npm install npm run build and npm run test ? you could also enable debug mode.

Comment: @Thomas How do I enable debug mode?

Comment: Give a [mre] - there's a whole job there that's unreachable, and we've no idea what your various scripts do.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging